# Is there a reason I continue to reach my daily query limit with this small test case?

Tags: python, google-places-api, geocoding, google-api-python-client

I am attempting learn some geocoding so that I can ultimately convert a csv file of addresses into their respective latitudes and longitudes. I am following the documented example on google's geocoding API instructional and continue to get an error stating that I have maxed out my daily request quota. The example I am following can be found here (https://github.com/googlemaps/google-maps-services-python). I get this error when trying to convert ONE single address as a test case... I will say that I am completely new to this and this is the first time I have used an API. Thanks for any help!

I have tried creating a new API key and using that. I have followed multiple tutorials on youtube and continue to get the error stating I have exceeded my daily limit

```
import googlemaps
from datetime import datetime
```

## Define our api key

```
API_KEY = 'Insert an API key here - for security purposes I left mine out'
```

## Define our client

```
gmaps = googlemaps.Client(key = API_KEY)
```

## Geocoding an address

```
geocode_result = gmaps.geocode('1 Wilson Road, Annapolis, MD 21412')
```

I want to be able to print out the latitude and longitude given the address I input.

Comment: You exceeded your daily limit with a single request on a brand new key?

Comment: This sounds like a question for Google. One thing I see is that google charges for geocoding calls, so you may not be able to make any with your API key without paying, depending how the key is set up

Comment: @Blorgbeard That is how it appears. The only request was the single address denoted in the code above. When looking at the statistics related to the API request the graph depicts a single spike at the time of the request.

Answer (score 2):

According to Google docs, geocoding is not free and billing has to be correctly set-up. See:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro

```
OVER_DAILY_LIMIT indicates any of the following:
    The API key is missing or invalid.
    Billing has not been enabled on your account.
    A self-imposed usage cap has been exceeded.
    The provided method of payment is no longer valid (for example, a credit card has expired).
```

And also
https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#over-limit-key-error
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/usage-and-billing
Reminder: To use the Geocoding API, you must include an API key with all API requests and you must enable billing on each of your projects.
**Priced** from "0.005 USD per each"
I read that all google maps terms changed quite recently, messing many people...